# Como obter no Arraylist em uma JSP e passar como parametro p/ um Servlet (Link)

Tags: jsp, servlet, arraylist, link

Essa lista tem o Id_livro,TituloLivro,AutorLivro, que está exibido na página corretamente. Só que eu quero criar um link para um Servlet passando o Id_livro. Como eu faço isso? Segue abaixo o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]